# How to move classes and resources to different targets in Xcode programatically via script or programming tool

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an Xcode project with multiple targets and I have created the classes and imported resources as well which are needed. I would like to know if there is a way where I can move my existing classes and resources belonging to a specific target to different Target in a Xcode project using any development tool or script which I can run to achieve this. I don't want to do the manual work rather run a script which will move all the classes and resources even app icons to different target.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should create a swift package and move all code and resources that is shared between targets to that package

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that will be manual, I want to do this via something like script, which will move the files in specific folder to a new target

Comment: It will be manual once but so will creating a script be.